# Web Form Submission to PDF email attachement

Tags: javascript, php, forms, pdf

Is it possible to turn a web form into a pdf when you click a submit button, then take that pdf and attach it to an email that is sent when the same submit button is clicked.

So the process would be

1. User completes form
2. User submits form
3. Contact details (i.e. Name and email) are captured and used with server side script (PHP) to create an email to a predefined address
4. The body is populated with a PDF that contains information the User completed in the form

Is there any JavaScript or PHP Library that might be able to help here?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and have you looked yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You should have looked by yourself indeed. Try TCPDF from TCPDF.org